# variable is not visible: Account.name

Tags: apex

I am very new to this programming. Can anybody please tell me how to rectify these errors:

```
ERROR:Variable is not visible: Account.name
ERROR:Variable does not exist: Industry
ERROR:DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Account
ERROR:Variable does not exist: id
```

Apex code:

```
public class create_record{
        public static void records()
        {
           
            Account acc=new Account();
            acc.name='john';
            acc.AccountNumber=123;
            acc.Industry='Banking';
            insert acc;
        }
}
```

Comment: AccountNumber is a Auto Number you need not assign value. Apart from that I dont see any issue in the class. Are you getting any error while running the class?

Comment: yes ,the first most thing when ever i am trying to insert account record .Its always showing me the ERROR. ERROR-Variable is not visible:Account .name

Comment: Are you creating the Account manually or creating by executing this script .

Comment: No ,not manually.

Comment: Can you send the script which you are executing while creating Contact

Comment: public class create_contact
{
    public static void record()
    {
        contact con=new contact();
        con.LastName='Peter';
        con.Birthdate=System.today();
        insert con;
        {
            system.debug('Created a contact record'+con);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Apologies for confusing you , As you are creating Account . You have an Apex class. How are you calling the Apex class. Can you share those details. So I can suggest based on it.

Comment: Classname.methodName();

Comment: I tried the below code by commenting the Account number `public class create_record{
        public static void records()
        {
           
            Account acc=new Account();
            acc.name='john';
            //acc.AccountNumber=123;
            acc.Industry='Banking';
            insert acc;
        }
}` and executed the below `create_record.records();` in anonomous window and Account got created successfully. Can you check again

Comment: Actually this is not the first time I am creating an account record .But Now a days i am facing the same error repeatedly. Thank you for you valuable time that you have spent with my problem. Still i don't know why I cant able to create a record on account object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors like this are typically a result of *shadowing*. Shadowing happens when you re-use the name of a variable or class.

The dead giveaway for me was

> ERROR:DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Account

So if you have an Apex class in your org named `Account`, Apex will find and use your custom Apex class instead of using the Account SObject. In most other situations, you could work around this by using the fully qualified class name (e.g. `System.JSON` instead of just `JSON`), but I don't think there's a good workaround for a shadowed SObject class name.

The general solution here is to find the offending Apex class and rename it. Then, take more care in naming things in the future.

Comment: yeah ,thank you .I have resolved that error. And yeah i will take more care while naming things.